# React native comunicación entre componentes

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-router-dom, react-redux

A ver si alguien me puede ayudar.
Soy nuevo en React-native.
El caso es que necesito comunicarme entre componentes:
me explico:
tengo la clase UploadFile y necesito acceder al nombre del archivo seleccionado que se ha guardado en el State desde la clase Register, es decir, a la variable documentName.
Gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Evita poner imágenes donde debería ir código, de esta manera tu pregunta será mejor recibida, saludos.

Comment: gracias, eso haré

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.